# How to save existing file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

My application allow users to create and edit text file, then these text files are saved to parse.com. the user can see all the files they have created. The user can click on one of the files and edit them. Once they have done editing, the file should be saved without creating a new file. How would I do this?

Comment: `parce.com` is not even a thing. Do you mean `parse.com`?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. Fixed the error

Comment: Please post the code you are using to save a new file to Parse DB

Answer (score 0):

If i want to update a file, I simply use object.set.

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File(newname, bytes);
var FileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
var query = new Parse.Query(FileClass);
query.find({
  success: function(results){
    for(var x = 0; x< results.length; x++){
    object = results[x];
     var codefilename = object.get('fileName');
     if (codefilename === newname){
      object.set('javaFile', parseFile);
      object.save();
     }
  }
 }
});
```